# Azure Build Pipeline cannot find dll's in VSTest v2 task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I get the following warning every time I run the build pipeline:

> No test sources found matching the given filter '**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*FunctionApp1*.dll,**\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*FunctionApp1*.dll

And though the pipeline is successful, the copy task cannot find the dll's and so none of my unit tests execute.  I have these set up with Visual Basics and have tried everything I can think of.

My YAML file looks like the following:

```
# Automatically trigger on merges / commits to 'main' branch
trigger:
- main

# Specify build agent image
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    solution: '**/*.sln'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*FunctionApp1*.dll
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*FunctionApp1*.dll
     !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I believe the following in the VSTask v2 is to blame, but I could be wrong.  Kind of new to YAML and this platform in general:

```
testAssemblyVer2: |
 **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*FunctionApp1*.dll
 **\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*FunctionApp1*.dll
```

My repo has the following dlls that I cannot seem to load in the VS Test task and therefore cannot copy:

```
AutomationTest/FunctionApp1Tests/bin/Release/net6.0/FunctionApp1.dll
```

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?  I really need to get past this issue so my automation can run in ADO.

Amended YAML file for the testAssemblyVer2 task and same results no matter what I try.  Also tried building in debug and release and attempted to clean up the repo.  Same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't specify any variable in your yaml file, so $(BuildConfiguration) can't be recognized. Please add the followings before your steps. See more info about variables from [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax).

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: Release
```

Then try the default VSTest@2 task and check the result.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

If your dlls can be found but you only want "AutomationTest/FunctionApp1Tests/bin/Release/net6.0/FunctionApp1.dll", you can use the followings as `testAssemblyVer2`, for example:

```
testAssemblyVer2: |
  **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*\FunctionApp1.dll
  !**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
  !**\obj\**
```

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick and my build pipeline now runs the test.  Thank you for your help.